# Using Pyomo for Solving complex equation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyomo

I have to solve a complex equation, here the decision variable is in pandas dataframe and constraints are defined from the pandas dataframe and the objective function is also defined from pandas dataframe.

my main problem is to create objective function we need to use the dataframe, however when the pandas dataframe is converted into pyomo decision variable, the inherent function of pandas dataframe that is iloc and loc is unavailable. However, I need iloc and loc for creation of the objective function.

Can anyone please help me on how to proceed. I am new and cannot get my way across this problem

A detail way on how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and your actual code. What is objective function?